# $f:\{1,2,3,4,5\} \longrightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $f(f(i)) \in \{1,2,3\}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

What is the number of functions
$f:\{1,2,3,4,5\} \longrightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $f(f(i)) \in \{1,2,3\}$ for $1 \le i \le 5$ ?
It's a very difficult problem, I can't find how to start in it
It will be very helpful if someone can solve it please.

Comment: Well, writing down some examples is always a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions.

1. It might be helpful to represent the dynamics of the map $f$ as a directed graph. To construct such a graph, draw an arrow from vertex numbered $j$ to vertex $f(j)$. The general geometrical structure of such a graph is a  disjoint collection of subgraphs. Each subgraph consists of a cycle which may have various disjoint trees attached to the various nodes on that cycle.  ( The subgraph is a collection of feeder routes that send you into a central roundabout).
2. It is probably easier to enumerate the  complementary set of graphs   that **fail** to satisfy the criterion $f\circ f$ has range cardinality at most three. Because you have only 5 nodes to play with, there are very few geometrical configurations that can fail.

Example. If any subgraph has a cycle of length 4 or 5, that graph  will certainly fail the criterion.

Here is one example that fails, to get you started. It contains a cycle whose length exceeds 3.

3. After you have all the possible  diagrams constructed you can count how many ways the nodes can be labeled with numbers.)[image]